# Assert.AreEqual failing in unit test

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, unit-testing, debugging

I have the following unit test:

```
string MtrlCode = "0";
Assessment target = new Assessment(MtrlCode);

List<string> EdgeCaseSymbolCodes = new List<string>(); //More than 3
EdgeCaseSymbolCodes.Add("FLA");
EdgeCaseSymbolCodes.Add("HAR");
EdgeCaseSymbolCodes.Add("COR");
EdgeCaseSymbolCodes.Add("ENVON");
EdgeCaseSymbolCodes.Add("ENVR");
EdgeCaseSymbolCodes.Add("EXP");

target.HazardSymbols = EdgeCaseSymbolCodes;

List<string> EdgeCaseSymbolCodesExpected = new List<string>(); //Should be 3
EdgeCaseSymbolCodesExpected.Add("FLA");
EdgeCaseSymbolCodesExpected.Add("HAR");
EdgeCaseSymbolCodesExpected.Add("COR");

System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(EdgeCaseSymbolCodesExpected[0] + EdgeCaseSymbolCodesExpected[1] + EdgeCaseSymbolCodesExpected[2] + " = \n" + target.HazardSymbols[0] + target.HazardSymbols[1] + target.HazardSymbols[2]);

Assert.AreEqual<List<string>>(EdgeCaseSymbolCodesExpected, target.HazardSymbols, "COSHH_2008.Custom_Classes.Assessment.setHazardSymbols Edge Case did not return the expected value.");
```

Which is testing an edge case (a time when the `List<string>` has more than 3 elements) with the desired output being the return of only the first 3.

Currently the test is failing and I've had to resort to using the `MessageBox` to see inside of the test (due to the breakpoints not being hit!).

From what I can see the elements are the same, however I realise there might be something else different with the `List<string>` object, but I can't see this as the breakpoints are never been hit.

I can't find the modules window in Visual Studio 2005.

What would your next steps be?

Comment: In what way is the test failing? Does the Assert fail (it probably should; `Assert.AreEqual` does probably not compare the contents of the lists)? Exceptions?

Comment: The Assert fails - I'm trying to debug exactly why.

Comment: The Assert fails, according to the docs "The assertion fails if the objects are not equal."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

References to lists are different, try instead

```
Assert.AreEqual(EdgeCaseSymbolCodesExpected[0], target.HazardSymbols[0]);
Assert.AreEqual(EdgeCaseSymbolCodesExpected[1], target.HazardSymbols[1]);
Assert.AreEqual(EdgeCaseSymbolCodesExpected[2], target.HazardSymbols[2]);
```

Comment: John W. S. Marvin has a more succinct solution using CollectionAssert.AreEqual()

Answer (score 14):

Use `CollectionAssert.AreEqual()`.

Answer (score 8):

If `Assert.Equals` uses the default comparer(no idea if it does) then this test will fail since `List<T>` uses referential equality by default.

If both lists have the same ordering you can use the linq extensionmethod [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) to test for element wise equality.

If you want to consider lists with the same elements equal even with different ordering you could use `a.Intersect(b).Count()==a.Unit(b).Count()` since there is no `SetEqual` extension method in Linq.

---

And even if it compared by value why do you expect a list containing 3 elements to be equal to a list containing 6 elements?

---

As a sidenote: Your naming conventions differ from the .net conventions. Usually local variable names start with lower case letters.

And I find the line `target.HazardSymbols = EdgeCaseSymbolCodes;` very strange. Does that mean you have a property of type `List<T>` with a public setter? I'd rather avoid those since that can lead to different objects using the same instance of a List which can have strange effects if they modify the list they own.

Comment: Assert.AreEqual() compares values, as opposed to Assert.AreSame() which compares references. In nUnit, that is.

Comment: This was just quickly hacked together, but I take your feedback.  Yes HazardSymbols has a public setter of type List<string>.

Comment: Unless `AreEqual()` has special support for collections built in it'll probably use the default equality comparison for that type. Which on list is referential.

Comment: I can understand about saying about two objects modifying the list, but since they're passed by value, not reference, the original list is always left intact.

Comment: @m.edmon Lists are passed by reference. Or are you using some extremely strange setter implementation? And why do you expect a list containing 3 elements to be equal to one containing 6?

Comment: Really?  I know objects are reference types but I didn't know they actually get passed by reference

Comment: Technically the reference gets passed by value. So saying the list gets passed by reference was a bit sloppy of me. But of course a copy of the reference still refers to the same instance.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think `Assert.AreEqual` supports collections.

You will have to write your own method that checks the number of elements in the collections and compares them individually.

You will have to supply your own logic for how **you define the equality of collections**, ie. if both collections contain the same elements but in different order, are they still equal?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your lists aren't the same. One has 3 elements and the other has 6, so I wouldn't expect them to be equal in the first place.

Second, the `List` class only compares as equals if they're the exact same list, not just lists with the same elements. In your case you want to use something like `Assert(EdgeCaseSymbolCodesExpected.SequenceEqual(target.HazardSymbols)` which will walk through each element of the lists, comparing each for equality.

Answer (score 1):

The `Assert` fails because it verifies whether the two lists are in fact the same instance. They are not; it's two different list instances. You will need to write code to verify that the two lists contains the same set of items.

Comment: You see this is exactly what I thought at first, but I have other unit tests which compare two completely separate lists but the Assert succeeds.

Comment: @m.edmondson: you should take a close look at those other unit tests and verify that they test what you think they do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare to List you can create a void function with that code Snippet.

```
Assert.AreEqual(response.Count, acceptedResponse.Count,"Diferent list length");
            for (int i = 0; i < acceptedResponse.Count; i++)
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(response[i],acceptedResponse[i]);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a case of reference versus value comparison. If you have two different instances of objects with the same property values, by default they will never be 'equal' using default comparisons. You have to compare the *values* of the objects. Try writing code to compare the values of each instance.

Answer (score 0):

I am also faced(ing) the same problem. As a work around you can check the count of the list, and do a for each and check for contains.

Answer (score 0):

Your actual List seems to contain more items than the expected List. Thus they are not equal.